# @required annotation in javascript files

Tags: javascript, annotations

I am at the starting point of trying to build a JavaScript library for our RIA application at work.  Currently we have lots of JavaScript files with functions all in global scope and I would like to attempt to put some reasonable namespace and context to our functions.  Possibly putting them into object form.

I've been looking at other open source libraries to help me understand the best way to build a library.  I see a lot of .js files with the following in one particular open-source project.

```
/**
 * @required OpenLayers/Map.js
 */
```

for example.

Does this have any meaning other than just being a comment in the file?
Is there some kind of way to import other .js files into your main build with this annotation or an import statement like in Java?

Answer (score 5):

This code is using JsDoc (http://jsdoc.sourceforge.net/) or something similar to create documentation from the source code, most likely.

Javascript doesn't actually have annotations.

Comment: You can use the @requires tag from JSDOC to document the dependency http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagRequires

Answer (score 4):

Choose [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). It is a JavaScript file and module loader. It implements the [CommonJS proposal](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/AsynchronousDefinition).

Comment: The poster is not inquiring into requiring files, but what kind of documentation style is shown in the example. It is a derivative of JavaDoc for Javascript.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: he says 'I would like to attempt to put some reasonable namespace and context to our fuctions'. RequireJS provides a framework to treat dependencies between JavaScript modules.

Comment: After rereading the last paragraph, I think you may be right. If the poster ever comes back, I suppose we'll find out.

Comment: namespacing is one of my goals.  I thought that the @required may be part of some tool that would help with some aspect of namespacing.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's a [PHPDoc](http://www.phpdoc.org/)-style comment, telling anybody working with the code that it will not work properly without `OpenLayers/Map.js`

Answer (score 1):

JavaDoc, the grandaddy of all code documentation/annotation systems for which all others (I think) are derived:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html